# Post File To Server with Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, upload

I use ajax post method to send Image to server.

Is it normal `Page_Load` event fires when post method is called  ?

Don't need to write `[WebMethod]` for this ?

By writting below code on `Page_Load` I can get Image from ajax:

```
       HttpFileCollection filesColl = Request.Files;
        foreach (string uploader in filesColl)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = filesColl[uploader];
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                SavePhotoDatabase.SaveCVPhoto(file);
            }
        }
```

Is it good idea or I should wirte `[WebMethod]`?

Comment: where is the ajax call here?

Comment: @AjuMon , If It's necessary for answer I can add.